# not send response of task modules (task/fetch) in case of success but show task module in case of failure

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards

we want to use task module to show error messages when user performs some action (by cliking submit button in adaptive card) which the user can not do. but in case of success we don't want to show any response.

i am facing issue that when I am calling "task/fetch" then a task module is expected (irrespective of the outcome).

Is the above scenario feasible?

Comment: Puh...as far as i know the task/fetch needs to be triggered by a button in MS Teams (messaging extension for example) no idea if you can send a task/fetch response from a card Activity. Interesting thought but even if its working probably not the UI/UIX expected. 

You can however return another card with an error message.

Comment: refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/task-modules/task-modules-tabs#adaptive-card-taskinfocard